# Problem with yarn when trying to set a ruby on rails application with react

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, yarnpkg

Following [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-rails-project-with-a-react-and-redux-front-end-8b01e17a1db/) tutorial I am stepping into odd errors in the very first steps.

After running:

```
rails new rails-react-tutorial --webpack=react
```

I would then try after `bundle install`

```
rails webpacker:install:react  rails generate react:installyarn install
```

And I will get:

```
[DEPRECATION] The trollop gem has been renamed to optimist and will no longer be supported. Please switch to optimist as soon as possible.
rails aborted!
ArgumentError: Malformed version number string Yarn v0.1.1 2011 Jesper Kjeldgaard
/*/rails-react-tutorial/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/*/rails-react-tutorial/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => webpacker:install:react => webpacker:verify_install => webpacker:check_yarn
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

After checking [this issue](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1461), I have removed the yarn files in the bin paths for the gems as it's advised in the last comments `versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yarn-0.1.1/lib/yarn.rb`,  but then I get errors like:

```
rails webpacker:install:react
rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- /*/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yarn-0.1.1/lib/yarn.rb
/*/rails-react-tutorial/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
/*/rails-react-tutorial/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
/*/rails-react-tutorial/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/*/rails-react-tutorial/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

So that will force me to install the gem again. I am using Rails 6.0.2.1-v and ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-linux].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/1051) and solved the issue:

```
for ver in $(rbenv whence yarn); do
  RBENV_VERSION="$ver" gem uninstall -ax yarn
  rm -f "$(rbenv prefix "$ver")/bin/yarn"
done
rbenv rehash
```

Answer (score 2):

The `yarn` tool you need is not a gem but the [Yarn package manager](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/). I suspect you have installed the [yarn gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/yarn/versions/0.1.1) which appears to be an old unused unrelated project.

Try on your command line:

```
gem uninstall yarn
```

Make sure you have the Yarn package manager installed. On a Mac, you can use Homebrew:

```
brew install yarn
```

Then retry the project installation commands, which should be:

```
rails webpacker:install:react 
rails generate react:install
yarn install
```

Comment: Doing that and later trying:

`rails new exampleproject --webpack=react`

I get
`
rbenv: yarn: command not found

The `yarn' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.6.2

Yarn not installed. Please download and install Yarn from https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/
`

Although now I am using ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-li

Comment: Is it on your path? i.e., `which yarn`

Comment: Yes `***/.rbenv/shims/yarn`

Comment: I've tried installing ruby 2.6.2 and setting it as default with `$ rvm use ruby-2.6.2 --default`  and then I get 

`
`to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0.a) among 47 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2:/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2@global', execute `gem env` for more information
`

Comment: If I use `gem install railties`  , then trying the same command to build the app `rails new example --webpack=react` I am getting:


 `block in materialize': Could not find nokogiri-1.10.7 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
Yarn not installed. Please download and install Yarn from https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/
`   (  this executes after `rails  webpacker:install ` )

Comment: That will give this sort of problems:
`
Traceback (most recent call last):
 1: from /*/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/bin/bundle:22:in <main>'
/*/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/bin/bundle:22:in load': cannot load such file -- /*l/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle (LoadError)
`

Comment: I am getting this now solely with the `webpack:react` flag :

`
ruby-2.6.2/gems/bundler-2.1.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:374:in block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable yarn for gem yarn. yarn is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile? (Gem::Exception)
`

Comment: Try removing the yarn gem from the system with `gem cleanup yarn`. Repeat: you don't want any version of the `yarn` gem on your system.

Comment: Hi, I have done that and it keeps prompting that error

Comment: I have solved the issue, I posted the used code above